# Why do we allocate memory for a linked list with a int data?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I have read this [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html) and I wonder why memory is allocated for `root`:

```
struct node {
  int x;
  struct node *next;
};
struct node *root;       
root = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
```

I would say that `struct node *root;` guarantees that memory is loaded in the stack no? There is no unknown size here. Moreover, we use this node in the same frame.

Comment: What memory? What stack? `struct node *root` is doing one thing - it allocates a *pointer* initialized to either `NULL` or some junk value (depending how declared).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right that you could use a stack allocated head node.  However the example is also considering how you will use the list after it is created.  If you want to insert a node at the start of the list it becomes more difficult because you now have to overwrite the head node instead of just replacing the pointer.  It also makes the list more homogenous.  You can pass a pointer to any node in your list to another function and it will know how to manipulate it.

Answer (score 3):

> I would say that struct node *root; guarantees that memory is loaded
>   in the stack no? There is no unknown size here. Moreover, we use this
>   node in the same frame.

Not quite. `struct node *root;` guarantees that there is memory to hold a *pointer* to a `struct node`, but not memory to hold the node itself. `malloc()` is allocating enough space for the node, and the address of that node is placed into `root`.

Comment: To the OP. The best way to think about pointers IMHO, is its just a uint32 or uint64 variable that stores an address. However, by declaring it such as 'node*', the compiler knows it's looking at the address of a 'node', versus it being any type of data. Consequently a (void*) pointer type can be anything.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* just declare it as `struct node root` and use it. But then it isn't a pointer, and it has to be treated differently from the other nodes. It is better for code consistency to treat all nodes the same, including the root node.

Answer (score 2):

`struct node *root;` gives you stack space (if in a function, if at top-level, it's global space) for a *pointer* to a `node`, but it doesn't allocate memory for the `node` itself. You could declare a `struct node root;` on the stack (no pointer), but it would disappear when the function returned, and common code intended to free or mutate the linked list might assume all nodes are dynamically allocated, causing serious problems if an attempt is made to `free` the `root`.